# How can I access the highest value of a nested element in a JSON data set using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I know there's a simple way to do this but I'm struggling to find it.  Not sure if JSON.parse() or findIndex() or something else would be best. ultimately I need to get the highest number value of the "Number" element and concatenate that with 2 other variables to make a 12 digit Unique ID. There could be 100 "Number" values. These are incremented based on application saves and I want to get the latest save which will be represented by the highest "Number" value. This example just has 2. The structure of the JSON text is as follows:

```
{
    "History": [
        {
            "Id": "244725",
            "Number": "1",
            "CreateDate": "2022-07-13 11:08:17.073",
            "AppStatus": "App Status",
            "DataElements": [
                {
                    "Id": "432",
                    "Name": "App Status",
                    "Value": "App Status",
                    "GroupId": "3",
                    "CustomLabel": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "244726",
            "Number": "2",
            "CreateDate": "2022-07-13 11:13:39.743",
            "AppStatus": "App Status",
            "DataElements": [
                {
                    "Id": "432",
                    "Name": "App Status",
                    "Value": "App Status",
                    "GroupId": "3",
                    "CustomLabel": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a function where I want to return the 3 concatenated values as a single 12 character string.

```
function main(applicationNumber, historyJson) {
    const x = 1;
    const appNum = applicatinNumber.substring(1);
    const history = JSON.parse(historyJson).History.Number.length - 1;

    return applicant += appNum += history;
}
```

This isn't working but my bigger issue is finding the best way to return the highest logged "Number" value.

Answer (score 0):

This would require recursion.  I have used the `iterate` function to traverse the entire object. Along the way I searched for the maximal `Number`.

```js
var data = {
  "History": [{
      "Id": "244725",
      "Number": "1",
      "CreateDate": "2022-07-13 11:08:17.073",
      "AppStatus": "App Status",
      "DataElements": [{
        "Id": "432",
        "Name": "App Status",
        "Value": "App Status",
        "GroupId": "3",
        "CustomLabel": null
      }]
    },
    {
      "Id": "244726",
      "Number": "2",
      "CreateDate": "2022-07-13 11:13:39.743",
      "AppStatus": "App Status",
      "DataElements": [{
        "Id": "432",
        "Name": "App Status",
        "Value": "App Status",
        "GroupId": "3",
        "CustomLabel": null
      }]
    }
  ]
}

var max_Number = -Infinity;

const iterate = (obj) => {
  if (!obj) {
    return;
  }
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    // console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${obj[key]}`)
    var value = obj[key]
    if (key == 'Number' && value > max_Number) {
      max_Number = value
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      iterate(obj[key])
    }
  })
}
iterate(data)
console.log(max_Number)
```

Comment: Just guessing from the question that the OP will need the object with the max number.  Probably should track max_number_object in your loop.  They probably want to do something with the id prop

Comment: I'm not sure  I should have iterated all of the tree because this data structure seem predictable

Comment: I should have read your code (not just run it). Yeah, the OP says "nested", but the nesting appears to be fixed.  Once you get inside, it's a flat array of objects.  This is just a reduce: `innerArray.reduce((a,b)=>a.Number>b.Number?a:b)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses.  Some of this is still very new to me so I may have used the wrong terminology.  This JSON is fixed in terms of the properties.  I'm still not sure how I dig into History.Number.  Do I need a for loop?  It's a large JSON that has the same structure over and over and each set of elements inside History are always the same but I need to return the highest value for "Number" every time it runs.

Comment: Do the one-liner by @danh should work

Comment: Alright, I've got this working!  I see that it actually returns the array where the "Number" value is the highest.  I had to turn around and extract the actual "Number" value and pass that value to another variable to use the padStart function so it will always return 3 numbers.  So if "Number": "8"; is returned then I have padStarte(3, "0") so it will return "008".  If it's "80" then it will return "080" and if it's "800" then it will return "800".  This value is concatenated at the end of my Unique ID so I have return variable1 + variable2 + Number; Thanks for all your help!